# how to change the color of the line in a nile graph in highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

How do I change the color of the line in a line chart in highcharts?

right now the line is appearing blue. What if I wanted it to be say, Red?

Right now I have the following code:

```
new Highcharts.Chart({
 chart: {
  renderTo: 'emissionsChart',
  type: 'areaspline',
  marginRight: 20
 },
  legend: {
   layout: 'vertical',
   align: 'center',
   verticalAlign: 'top',
   x: 0,
   y: 40,
   floating: true,
   borderWidth: 1,
   backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'
 },
  xAxis: {
   labels: {
       formatter: function() {
           return this.value.toFixed(0);
       }
   }
 },
  yAxis: {
   title: {
      text: 'Emissions (tCO2e)'
   }
  },
 credits: {
  enabled: false
  },




plotOptions: {
  areaspline: {
      fillOpacity: 0.5
   }
 },
  series: [{"name":"High reduction rate","data":[]}]
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify whatever color you want - among many other things - in the plotOptions:

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.color

You can do this on a series by series basis by adding the property to your series object instead, as well:

http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/yPLVP/8/

```
series:[{
  color:'orange',
  data:[5,2,8,9,6,3,4,7,7]
}
```